# How to open Mobile-Angular-ui modal from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen the demo to show pop-up
http://mobileangularui.com/demo/#/overlay

In the example has been used Directive into template

```
ui-turn-on="modal1"
```

I need to activate the pop-up from controller.

I think I have to use SharedState, but I was unable to create a working example.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem.

The following code solved my problem:

```
$rootScope.Ui.turnOn('modal1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the SharedState in the controller and then just use it like this:

```
SharedState.turnOn('name_of_modal_id');
```

and/or

```
SharedState.turnOff('name_of_modal_id');
```

Does not require anything special.
Its simple.